# How to maintain state of pages in TabBarView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test, flutter-navigation, flutter-appbar

I have used TabBarView as my page holder for BottomNavigationBar instead of Indexed stack. But this does refresh the page every time tab is changed. The state is not maintained. What to do?

Comment: It looks like problem with your code. Can you add some code?

Answer (score 0):

Using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` [flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html)

```
class _SampleScaffoldSate extends State<SampleScaffold> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  // ... other code

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

}
```